# проблема при скачке discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

https://youtu.be/0VkHqQ4vIKY
пробовал все  варианты ничего не помогло

ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: `Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/` Если коротко, то [скачать](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/) или приведите ваши попытки, если это уже пробовали

Comment: пробовал скачивать все эти библиотеки что там пишет не помогло пробовал по видео с ютуба одни и те же ошибки если можно было где-то с вами связаться по звонку напишите куда

Comment: Так, ну смотри. Вариант первый: если у тебя двенадцатый питон — откатывай его на одиннадцатую версию, это может быть проблемой обновлений. Вариант второй: скачиваешь Microsoft C++ Build Tools (или как оно там называется) и это должно исправить проблему. Если и это не помогает, пробуй устанавливать pyproject.toml, обновлять wheels, cmake, buildtools, сам pip и прочее. Как правило, этот набор помогает.

Comment: Приведи, кстати, полный текст ошибки (это же не полный, правда?).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects скачивал  install pyproject.tom такая же ошибка

Comment: Ты попробуй сделать все что я говорю: откатить питон, обновить pip и библиотеки. И то, что ты приводишь — это конец ошибки. До этого должен быть трейсбэк. Приведи скрин, если не хочешь давать текстом.

Comment: спасибо помогло с понижением пайтона!